# Doctrine 2 LifecycleCallbacks with abstract base class are not called

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have this situation:

Abstract Class:

```
abstract class AbstractBase
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="updated_at")
     * @var \DateTime $updatedAt
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt()
    {
        die('THIS POINT IS NEVER REACHED');
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

Concrete Class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User extends AbstractBase
{
    // some fields, relations and setters/getters defined here, these all work as expected.
}
```

Then i call it in my controller like this:

```
$user = $this->em->find('Entity\User', 1);
// i call some setters here like $user->setName('asd');
$this->em->flush();
die('end');
```

Everything works as expected, so the id field from the abstract class gets created for the User entity, i can access it etc.
The problem is, that the line "die('THIS POINT IS NEVER REACHED')" is never reached. (Note the @ORM\PreUpdate) This means that lifecycleCallbacks are not called on
inherited objects. Is this a bug, or is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your abstract base class has to be anotated as **Mapped Superclasses** and include the **HasLifecycleCallbacks**-Annotation.

Further Information: [Inheritance Mapping in the Doctrine Documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
abstract class AbstractBase
{
    [...]

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends AbstractBase
{
    // some fields, relations and setters/getters defined here, these all work as expected.
}
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get the above to work - the callbacks still never fire even with the MappedSuperclass annotation - with symfony standard edition 2.1.6 - can anyone confirm or deny?

Comment: check if you have any empty PreUpdate handler in you child (user) class, if the children has one, the parents handlers will not be called.

Answer (score 3):

You have to annotate the base class with `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks`, and the function with `@ORM\preUpdate`

You have a typo (PreUpdate should be preUpdate), also preUpdate isn't called on creation (only on update).  So if you want it also be triggered on creation, you should add `@ORM\prePersist`.

Comment: I dunno how it was in 2012, but in 2021 those annotation refer to classes, and classes use Pascal-case so annotation is correct when capitalised (`PreUpdate`).

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted reply is correct for the general case, in this particular case (timestamp) you actually want to use the doctrine extension Timestampable as explained for example here [Lifecycle Callback Issue When Extending FOSUserBundle User Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806184/lifecycle-callback-issue-when-extending-fosuserbundle-user-entity)

Answer (score 2):

It is important that the MappedSuperclass with HasLifecycleCallbacks is in the same namespace or directory as their child Entities.

I had problems with life cycle callbacks when the MappedSuperclass was in one directory (Model) while the Entities were in another (Entity). Putting the MappedSuperclass in the same directory as the Entities (Entity) solved the issue.

Comment: and what if I can't move the parent class into the same directory because of the structure of my project?

Comment: Mmm, then I don't know. Maybe that is something the SensioLabs team should look at...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i'm wrong but I don't think preUpdate isn't triggered when you persist an entity. You should have a @prePersist.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/events.html

But still then i'm not sure this is going to work but you could try that. Else a workaround would be to overwrite the setUpdatedAt function and just call his parent one but that's a bit ugly.

Hope the @prePersist helps for you.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was an error in my sample-code i fixed it now (removed the $em->persist($user); line). So that is not it :/

Comment: Also, the problem really is that no callbacks are called at all for extended classes, i tried them all.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could this [issue report](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1034?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) as a reference how to setup your annotations? The testcase seems to be valid and matches your use case.

Comment: I just tried that, @PostLoad seems to work, but none of the database ones (PreUpdate, PrePersist ...).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to annotate the base class with @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks

[docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-preupdate)

Comment: have you included it like : `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()`

Comment: parenthesis don't matter, it'll work with or without them