# How can I call a initialization method for all my models in doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Im using Doctrine2 and I have a fair amount of model Objects.

All the objects inherit from a base class called BaseModel, and I need that every object call a method when its constructed. Since Doctrine doesnt call __construct, i cannot use that.

And from what I've seen, if I wanted to use the life cycle methods, I would have to modify all of my objects, they are over 50 of them...

Is there a way to define in one place a common life cycle method?

Comment: can the BaseModel constructor call the method?

Comment: @marabutt Doctrine's entity manager does not call class constructors on entity loading so that is not an option

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2 LifecycleCallbacks with abstract base class are not called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320425/doctrine-2-lifecyclecallbacks-with-abstract-base-class-are-not-called)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `BaseModel` to be a [mapped superclass](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) with the [appropriate life cycle callbacks](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks), eg

```
/** @MappedSuperclass @HasLifecycleCallbacks */
class BaseModel
{
    /** @PostLoad */
    public function doStuffOnPostLoad()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation says "This means that One-To-Many assocations are not possible on a mapped superclass at all.". And my classes do have one-to-many associations... Would you think it will work anyway?. Also note that I have non persisted clases extending this model too

Comment: You cannot have one-to-many relationships defined in the mapped superclass itself (`BaseModel`) however your entities may define them as usual AFAIK

Comment: Cool, in this case BaseModel is just an abstract class, nothing refers to it, but all the classes extends from it. So no problem with subclases of that referencing each other or having table iheritance?

Comment: @HernanRajchert Shouldn't be a problem