# Symfony2.4 abstract class callbacks are not triggered

Tags: php, symfony, mappedsuperclass

I use a class that extend an abstract class containing lifecyclecallbacks. My abstract class is annotated with @ORM\MappedSuperclass but my callbacks are not triggered.
I saw a lot of problems here and there on this subject but no concrete answers. Has anyone have a solution that really works?
(I specify that if I call my callback methods manually everything works perfectly)

The answer on this link dont work for me :

[Doctrine 2 LifecycleCallbacks with abstract base class are not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320425/doctrine-2-lifecyclecallbacks-with-abstract-base-class-are-not-called)

(but the problem is the same)

```
<?php

// ...

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
abstract class Picture {

    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload() {
        echo 'preUpload ';
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            $this->picture = $this->getNewFilename(10);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Myown\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends Picture  {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add abstract class and the Entities using that mappedsuperclass? It still sounds like it misses some specifications.

Comment: edited but i dont think the code will help you more. 
(The probleme is the same as linked)